# How to add an Image side to the back button in navigation bar

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, navigationbar

I am working on xamarin. form application, where I need to add a image side to the
back button in the navigation bar.

I have tried 
1. `<NavigationPage.TitleView><image/></NavigationPage.TitleView>` -here the view is away from the back button. the space between back button and image is more.
2. created a custom navigation as following.

```
            <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding ActionbarColor}">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Image Source="back.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding MoveBackCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <Imge Source="defaultUser.png">
                <Label />
                <Label  x:Name="TitleLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
```

with 2nd, the view is blinking while navigating to the back view.

Apart of these two are there any ways to display the image in the navigation bar side the back button

Answer (score 0):

Use Grid to Change

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ColumnSpacing="0">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <BoxView BackgroundColor="Aqua" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
  <Button Image="BackIcon" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Command="GoBack"/>
  <Image Source="Logo" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"/>
</Grid>
```

It not works follow [this](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/02/creating-an-identical-custom-navigation-bar-back-button-in-xamarin-ios/) - if it works let me know